# Issue with DNS Resolution in Celery/Redis on Debian 12 - VPS Provider Specific

Tags: networking, debian, redis, celery

I'm facing a peculiar issue with DNS resolution in a Celery/Redis setup on some Debian 12 installations. It seems that the problem might also relate to the VPS network settings. I'm at a loss and would greatly appreciate any expert guidance.

We use Celery to execute tasks every 40 seconds, utilizing a local Redis as the queue. Each task writes the current timestamp to a central remote Redis:

```
def create_redis_connection_sync():
    return redis.Redis(
        host=settings.REDIS_URL,
        password=settings.REDIS_PASSWORD,
        port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
        db=settings.REDIS_DB,
        decode_responses=True,
    )

info = {"timestamp": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
redis_instance = create_redis_connection_sync()
redis_instance.hset(settings.REDIS_VPN_SUBDOMAIN, mapping=info)
redis_instance.close()
```

This configuration works seamlessly on over 60 Debian 12 VPSs in our company. However, a recent VPS from a different provider behaves anomalously. The execution time for tasks drastically increases from 1.38 seconds to 131 seconds if systemd-resolved.service is stopped.

```
[2023-12-20 08:23:18,879: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task notify.tasks.push[7e2d2856-a472-4b49-8859-2729b5bc0b0b] succeeded in 1.3803006149973953s: None
[2023-12-20 08:25:58,725: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task notify.tasks.push[c116f662-e506-4076-9b42-32f4acd8df78] succeeded in 131.22602167900186s: None
```

All systems uniformly use the following /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

The configurations for Redis and Celery are consistent across all VPS servers.

I'm trying to understand:

1. Why is this particular VPS so dependent on systemd-resolved.service, unlike the others?
2. This VPS doesn't have /etc/network/interfaces, and /etc/systemd/network/ is empty. Where else should I be looking?
3. I want to disable systemd-resolved.service because it conflicts with AdGuard, which uses the same port. Here's the output of sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w '53':

```
tcp        0      0 172.16.96.0:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      496/AdGuardHome
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12115/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12115/systemd-resol
```

- Is it possible to configure the system to not rely on systemd-resolved.service for DNS resolution when /etc/resolv.conf is already present?
- If all else fails, is it problematic that systemd-resolved.service and AdGuard are both listening on port 53, considering AdGuard is primarily bound to the 172.16.96.0 subnet used by Wireguard VPN? Because currently The Wireguard clients can still connect to Adguard despite the port being shared.

Any insights or suggestions would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.